# The correct pronunciation of this phrase?

Tags: grammar, meaning, pronunciation

I'd like to know which way is the proper way to say **あなたたちは早行きました**。 The correct pronunciation of this phrase would be:

> anata tachi ha sou ikimashita or anata tachi ha hayai ikimashita

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't a correct pronunciation for this phrase, because 早行きました is not a grammatical expression. Perhaps what you want to say is 早{はや}く行{い}きました.

Comment: Why did you use く before 行きました? And I mispelled hayai with hiyai I'm sorry :/

Comment: Because 早い (note the い on the end) is an adjective, and 早く is the adverbial form.